# Unable to access file system via RemoteApp but works fine in RDP session

Tags: windows, active-directory, remote-desktop

I've written a program that accesses a file on a remote server, through a remotely mounted drive on another server.

The program runs fine (is able to access the file) when I start an RDP session, and I launch it like I would if I had it on the desktop in front of me.

Using a RemoteApp .rdp file, with the same credentials, the program puts out an error saying it doesn't have permission. Why is this? And what is the solution?

I've verified that the program is the same, so it's not that the link is pointing to the wrong program.